# How to let select user individual word or row in a Django and process accordingly?

Tags: django

I have a rows or words like this:

```
hello
ok 
there
hi
```

I want to let the user select each row, store that row in variable and process that using the DJango view. How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not exactly sure how you want the user to select each row, but here's a simple example if you want to use a checkbox, letting the user make a selection from a defined list in the index page and process it however you want in the vote view (stored in the choices list variable):

in your views.py:

```
def index(request):
    mylist = ["hello", "ok", "there", "hi"]
    return render_to_response('testing/index.html', {'mylist': mylist}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def vote(request):
    choices = request.POST.getlist('choice')
    return render_to_response('testing/vote.html', {'choices': choices})
```

and in the index.html:

```
<form action="/vote/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in mylist %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice}}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

and for example in the vote.html:

```
<html>
<table border="1">
{% for x in choices %}
<tr><td>{{ x }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</html>
```

(A modified ripoff from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial04/:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these rows are on the web page, use some jQuery to process clicking/selecting the row and pushing it to a django view.

For example, this type of thing (very rough pseudo code):

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>hello</tr>
<tr>ok</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( {
    $('table tr').onClick(function(){
        $(this).style('color','green'); // to show that its selected
        $.ajax({  type: 'POST',  url: 'django/url',  data: JSON_stringify($(this).text()),   dataType: dataType});
    });
});
```